# Need for disabling Viewstate

Tags: asp.net

I understand the use of View state. Any material that talks about view state, explains the need and use of it. However there is an option provided at every control level/ page level to disable it as well.

In what circumstances we might want to disable the viewstate of a page or control?

From an online material, I read that,

> If the page doesn't have any dynamic data, data to be persisted
>   between round trips we can disable viewstate.

I agree to this statement, but what's the advantage of doing this? What do we get out of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some pages have HUGE viewstates. As such it takes time to send back and forth, its more load on the server, more network traffic, etc. There's no need for it a lot of times, so your apps will be quicker by shrinking your viewstate.

Take note even fully disabling viewstate at times will generate still a small required viewstate because of control requirements, but it can be greatly reduced. I've seen viewstates go into 200kb per page.

Answer (score 2):

1. You get less payload since the ViewState hidden value gets set to "". In datagrids displaying several thousands of records, the ViewState can become several MB in size
2. Performance is improved not only because the ViewState is not transferred anymore, but also because reading ViewState is typically an expensive operation since it involves decrypting it and deserializing the value.

Actually, you can improve performance just by disabling the encryption of the ViewState but this is not a good security practice.

Answer (score 1):

As the page has to render the ViewState to the client it can speed up load times if the ViewState is disabled.

Around the time that .Net was introduced I remember trouble shooting a page that was loading slowly, the page was rendering a sizeable grid all of which was been saved into ViewState. Removing the data from the ViewState made a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

ViewState is rendered as a hidden input field in the web page. This makes the page load more slowly, and also makes post backs slower, since the ViewState must be posted along with everything else.

Therefore, your page will perform faster if you disable ViewState. How much faster? Hard to say.

In general, if you don't need ViewState, disable it.

Note also that even if you disable ViewState, there will still be a hidden control with a small amount of data that is neccessary for .NET.

Answer (score 1):

When I display info or error messages to the user as asp:Label or asp:Literal controls, I almost always set EnableViewState to false, because they almost always apply only to a given post-back.  Setting EnableViewState to false means I never have to write this in my code-behind:

```
lblSomethingWentWrong.Text = string.Empty;
```